# Explode database array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'm trying to breakdown a paragraph, retrieved from a database array, into separate words. Is this the right way to go about doing it because it is currently giving an error saying explode() expects 2 parameters, so it must not be picking up the $row array.

```
function words() {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM table WHERE textID = 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $e[] = explode(" ", $row);
            foreach($e as $r) {
                echo $r;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function words() {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM table WHERE textID = 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $e[] = explode(" ", $row[0]);
            foreach($e as $r) {
                echo $r;
            }
        }
    }
```

$row is array. Choose first element to explode. Read documentation for [Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: I missed that part. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
function words() { 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM table WHERE textID = 1"); 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
            $e[] = explode(" ", $row[0]); 
            foreach($e as $r) { 
                echo $r; 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc will return to you array with "text" field

Comment: Oops didnt notice that he is using mysql_fetch_array.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong functions architecture here.
You don't need `words()` function at all. `explode` is enough.
While you strongly need a function to get data from mysql, which is apparently unrelated to your explode needs.
Also note that a function should never do any output but retirn values only (save for the functions intended for the output only).

So, the function could be

```
function dbgetvar($query){
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    trigger_error("dbget: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
    return FALSE;
  }
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
  if (!$row) return NULL;
  return $row[0];
}
```

And your code become as simple as

```
$text  = dbgetvar("SELECT text FROM table WHERE textID = 1");
$words = explode(" ",$text);
foreach ($words as $w) echo $w;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function words() {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM table WHERE textID = 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $e = explode(" ", $row);
            foreach($e[0] as $r) {
                echo $r;
            }
            }
    }
```

The $row is populated entirely with the field value therefore $e[0] is the right variable.